# Equivalent conditions for invertible matrices - confused on conclusion my book draws

Tags: linear-algebra

My book lists the following equivalent conditions:

- A is invertible
- Ax = b has a unique solution for every b
- det(A) =/= 0

And then asks which of the following systems has a unique solution:

(to avoid typing out the entire systems I'm just going to type out their coefficient matrices)

a)
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & 2 & -1 \\
3 & -2 & 1\\
3 & 2 & -1
\end{vmatrix}
= 0
$$

b)
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & 2 & -1 \\
3 & -2 & 1\\
3 & 2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
= -12
$$

And draws the conclusion that only the second system has a unique solution.

I get why the second system has a unique solution. But why does the fact that a) has a determinant of 0 mean it DOESN'T have a unique solution? All the equivalent conditions list said was that if the determinant is nonzero, it has a unique solution. It says nothing about conditions when the determinant IS zero. Isn't it some kind of logical fallacy to conclude that a) does not have a unique solution given this list? Maybe it's not, but I just can't see it.

Comment: When we say two conditions (a) and (b) are equivalent, the meaning is that both are true for a matrix or both are false for a matrix.  So a matrix has  nonzero determinant if and ONLY if it is invertible which is if and only if the system of equations has a unique solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I didn't know that was the meaning of equivalent. That clears things up.